# using ajax to login with php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to use window.location = "userpage.php"; after a successful login but the page does not redirect.
I am using Ajax and a modal form in my code

Everything works fine. I don't get any errors. I check the network headers. and there is no response in the network 
I have not been able to figure out the issue.
 I have tried

`window.location.href`

`window.location.replace`.

Nothing is working
 need help
Thanks

This is part of the js file

```
    $("#loginform").submit(function(event) {
    //prevent default php processing
    event.preventDefault();
    //collect user inputs
    var datatopost = $(this).serializeArray();
    //send them to login.php using AJAX
      $.ajax({
      url: "login.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: datatopost,
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == "success") {
          window.location = "user_page.php";
        } else {
          $("#loginmessage").html(data);
        }
      },
      error: function() {
        $("#loginmessage").html(
          "<div class='alert alert-danger'>There was an error with the Ajax Call. Please try again later.</div>"
        );$
      }
    });
  });
```

This is part of my login.php file

```
//Start session
session_start();
//Connect to the database
include("connection.php");
...
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $email);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $password);
$password = hash('sha256', $password);
    //Run query: Check combinaton of email & password exists
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password' AND activation='activated'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Error running the query!</div>';
    exit;
}
    //If email & password don't match print error
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($count !== 1) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Wrong Username or Password</div>';
} else {
//log the user in: Set session variables
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];

     if (empty($_POST['remember'])) {
         echo "success";
     } else {
  // todo logic for remember me 
}
}
```

This is the form modal

```
//Start session
session_start();
//Connect to the database
include("connection.php");
...
<form method="post" class="login_form modal" id="loginform">
  <div class="form-body">
    <div class="form-head"><h3>Login form</h3></div>
    <div class="form-logo"><img src="/dist/img/logo.svg" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="loginmessage"></div>
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" /></p>
      <p><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" /></p>
    </div>
    <div class="login-session">
      <div class="remember">
        <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember" value="remember" />
        <label for="remember">Remember me</label>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <a href="#reset_password" rel="modal:open">Forgot my password</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-submit">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="log in"/>
      <a class="btn btn-small" href="#signupform" rel="modal:open">register</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't see a `session_start()` in your PHP code? Also, you should use prepared statements to access your user database, and you should use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to store and test your passwords. Also you don't seem to be echoing `success` when your PHP succeeds, but that is what your ajax code is looking for.

Comment: @Nick this is just the part of the code i thought was worth posting. i have the session_start(); in all the files

Comment: I understand, but there isn't enough information to debug it. You could always add `session_start();` then a `...` at the top of your code to indicate that it is there. Most importantly though, since your ajax code is looking for the word `success` to enable redirection (which is your problem) it is important to see all the code that generates a response.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution to the issue.

In the index.js file:

```
success: function(data) {
   if (data == "success") {
      window.location = "user_page.php";`
```

was changed to:

```
success: function(data) {
   if ($.trim(data) == "success") {
      window.location = "user_page.php";`
```

Because the response message success for some reason had whitespace in it. I trimmed all whitespace and it worked.

Comment: Does it continue to work with `===` instead of `==`? It might be coercion, in which case it only *appears* to work and is introducing a bug that will be difficult to track down later.

Comment: @JeremyHarris yes I tried `===` and it works. So which is the better option according to you?

Comment: The `===`, per the documentation.